# php - Function variable declared to null. Why?

Tags: php, function

I have been editing an existing php script and have come across a function as so

`function functionName($var1 = null, $var2 = null, $var3 = null)`

I'm not sure why you would declare a `var` as null in this way. I have tried looking for an answer online but google pulls up anything but this example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are default values for the parameters, allowing them to be omitted.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are default values: you don't have to specify them when you call the function. When you omit them, the default value will be used.

See [example #3 on this manual page.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) From there:

```
<?php
function makecoffee($type = "cappuccino")
{
    return "Making a cup of $type.\n";
}
echo makecoffee();
echo makecoffee(null);
echo makecoffee("espresso");
?>
```

will output

```
Making a cup of cappuccino.
Making a cup of .
Making a cup of espresso.
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined with `NULL` as the identifier of the default variable. See [example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-155) on the documentation for functions in the PHP manual.

The argument `$var1` is optional and is not required. If specified, the given value will be used. If not, the value specified as the default value will be used.

Another example:

```
function sayHello($person = 'stranger') {
    return "Hello, $person";
}

echo sayHello('Rob');
echo sayHello('Tom');
echo sayHello();
```

It will output:

```
Hello, Rob
Hello, Tom
Hello, stranger
```

Refer to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for more information.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a default value : when you call the function, if you don't set a value to $var it will take the default one.

For example :

```
function foo($bar = 'default')
{
    return $bar;
}

echo foo(); // Will display "default"
echo foo('Hello world!'); // Will display "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

when you put in a value  into a parameter  like this mean, if you don't pass a nothing 'lol'(or other value) will be default.

```
   function foo($param1 = 'lol'){
     echo $param1;
   }


   foo(); //'lol';
   foo('new foo'); // new foo
```